# Why the garbage collector does not free memory

Tags: c#, list, memory, garbage-collection

I have a list to which type "IJornalEnrty" elements are added. And there is a task that slowly reads the list. Since the list is a shared resource, it is accessed through a lock. The list item must be written to the database table, and in order not to block it for a long time, the memory is copied and the item is removed from the list.
As a result of the task of reading the list, the memory is constantly growing, and even when the list is completely empty, the memory is not cleared.

```
public interface IJornalEnrty
{
    string device { get; set; }
    string action { get; set; }
    string date { get; set; }
    IJornalEnrty Clone();
}
public struct JornalEnrty : IJornalEnrty
{
    public string device { get; set; }
    public string action { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public JornalEnrty(params string[] p)
    {
        device = p[0];
        action = p[1];
        date = p[2];
    }
    public IJornalEnrty Clone ()
    {
        return new JornalEnrty(String.Copy(device), String.Copy(action), String.Copy(date));
    }
}
static async void InsertEntryAsync(object o)
    {
        CancellationToken cancel = (CancellationToken)o;
        string sql = "";
        while (!cancel.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            IJornalEnrty entry = null;
            await GetEntryListLoker.WaitAsync();
            entry = EntryList[0]?.Clone();
            EntryList.RemoveAt(0);
            GetEntryListLoker.Release();
            await SaveEntry(entry);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The garbage collector is non-deterministic.  It's not like C++ destructors.  Memory isn't simply freed the second it's no longer used.  You can force a collection using `GC.Collect` but I would advise against it.

Answer (score 2):

Because the GC only runs when it is needed and there is memory pressure. Period. Your debugger should have a memory profile view showing when every of the GC tiers are collecting and you likely will see that it simply is not felling it necessary to run.

Comment: And I already thought that implementation `IDisposable` is necessary for my `IJornalEnrty`.

Comment: IDisposable does not clean up managed memory. It is there to allow a class to get rid of non-managed-ressources, i.e. file handles etc. - that need to close AT A POINT IN TIME. it will NOT handle any managed memory. More reading to do on the basics ;)